# "can" or "do" to use with the verb "like"

Tags: word-choice

> She is so aggressive that people **cannot like** her.
>
> She is so aggressive that people **do not like** her.

Which is suitable for using with the verb "like", can or do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She is so aggressive that people cannot like her.
>
> She is so aggressive that people do not like her.

'cannot' by definition means 'to be **unable** to do otherwise', so to me, one sentence implies choice, the other does not.

Another way of wording it would be...

> She is so aggressive that people are unable to like her.
>
> She is so aggressive that people decide to not like her.

..which makes the distinction slightly clearer.

Of course, writers sometimes use 'cannot' in this context for effect - basically to state that this person is so aggressive that no person on earth could possibly like her.